# Best practice to convert a Double to a String

Tags: java, string, casting, type-conversion, double

I am currently using

```
Double a = 0.00;

for(condition)
    //Do things

String result = "" + a;
```

Would using

```
String result = a.toString();
```

Provide any real benefit compared to what I have now. Does this just help the compiler or are there any differences between the two methods?

Comment: If people are going to downvote my question could they please explain why?

Comment: My guess is that downvotes may be caused by fact that question wasn't clear, since in title you ware asking about `double` and in question itself about `Double` (those types are related but not same thing).

Comment: Aaah okay thanks @Pshemo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version - `String result = "" + a` under the hood is the same as `String result = "" + a.toString();`. Whenever there is a concatenation of String + Object the `toString` method is called.

What is the best practice here? What looks better for you. I'd probably go with the first version.

If you're concerned about the performance of both - `String result = a.toString();` on paper will be faster because you don't need to create / get an empty String just to create a new one. However, as with many things in Java, something like that most likely gets optimized by JIT compiler anyway so I wouldn't worry about it too much. Even if it doesn't you shouldn't worry about optimization prematurely - if your code runs slowly then usually there is something else wrong with it that is much bigger than that.

Answer (score 1):

**I think second option is better** because **concatenation of strings cost much more memory**.Since Strings are immutable objects in the first way your memory is wasting for store a Double  object + two String Objects .

But in the second option it only create one new String object only .So in your memory there will only be one Double object + one String Object.